if the product has multiple images from the image table that shows it, and if it does not exist
How can I do condition if the product has multiple images from the image table that shows it, and if it does not exist, it appears empty
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-primary">
            {{ App\Models\Project\Ecommerce\ProductImage::where('product_id', $product->id)->count() }}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>


        // mutli image Product //
        @if (!empty($product->images))
            <img src="{{ asset('Image/ProductImage/'. $product->images->pull('0')->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->title_image }}" class="object-fit-contain" width="50" height="50">
        @endif
        // end mutli image Product //


    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach

Attempt to read property "image" on null

use foreach inside if statement
    @if (!empty($product->images))
@foreach($product->images as $image
            <img src="{{ asset('Image/ProductImage/'. $image->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->title_image }}" class="object-fit-contain" width="50" height="50">
@endforeach
        @endif


if the images relationships is available on your product model it will work definitely.

Unfortunately it doesn't work
How can I display pictures if there are pictures and if they are not, a blank appears

@Mahmoud you can check the if condition to $product->images()->count() != 0
This will check if the relationship`s count is not 0.
there are other ways too as $product->images()->exists() to check the existence of the images relationship

$product->images()->count() != 0
That's right, it worked, thank you very much
